# Refresh a Partial View using OnChange of an Input textbox that is inside that Partial View (C# .Net Core)

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, .net-core

I have a Form.cshtml with a partial view:

```
<form asp-action="Form">
   <div id="partialDiv">
       @Html.Partial("_SubletOrderLines")
   </div>
</form>
```

On the same Form.cshtml, I also have this script:

```
$("#QtyOrder").change(function () {
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: '/controllername/ComputerOrder?OrderNo=' + Model.OrderNo + '&orderQty=' + $(this).val(),
                type: 'GET',
                data: "",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#partialDiv").html(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
    });
```

Inside my partial view (_SubletOrderLines), I have this input text:

```
<td>
    <input type="text" asp-for="@item.Qty" class="form-control" id="QtyOrder" />
</td>
```

My problem is that script is not firing on text change. Am I doing something wrong here? 
I can successfully call the controller via url so I think ComputerOrder has no problem.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, remove the content-type in your ajax call

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the help. Done that also but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call text change event of text box which is in partial view means which will not be available at the DOM rendering. That's why your change event is not getting triggered. Try to update your change event with below syntax.

```js
$(document).on("change","#QtyOrder",function(){
  $.ajax(
            {
                url: '/controllername/ComputerOrder?OrderNo=' + Model.OrderNo + '&orderQty=' + $(this).val(),
                type: 'GET',
                data: "",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#partialDiv").html(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error");
                }
});
```

`$(document).on()` will work.
Thanks

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help and I've tried your suggestion but still not working..